# Getting "not a valid column name" for column name I do not refer to, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, linq, mapping

I am trying to get started with LINQ to Excel and mapping columns to object properties but I have a very strange run-time error and I can't get my head around what's causing it. The error states:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.DataException' occurred in LinqToExcel.dll
>
> **'oDateTime(-1.EDI_date' is not a valid column name**. Valid column names are: 'EDI Date', 'Week No', 'Dist No#', 'Cust Type ', 'Cust No#', 'Site No#', 'Date ', 'Time', 'Card No#', 'Reg', 'Bunker Sheet ', 'Mileage',

Which is weird because I never refer to any column by the name "oDateTime(-1.EDI_date" it seems that the Convert.ToDateTime function is being parsed as a string or something?

The following block is the function that does the LINQ query:

```
public IEnumerable<EDI> getEDIs()
    {
        // Set date of last monday
        DateTime lastMonday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek - 6);

        // Initialise Excel file
        var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(DIRECTORY);

        // Create column mappings
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.EDI_date, "EDI Date");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Week_no, "Week No");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Dist_no, "Dist No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Cust_no, "Cust No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Site_no, "Site No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Card_no, "Card No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Mileage, "Mileage");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Quantity, "Quantity");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Product_no, "Product No");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Month_no, "Month No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Month_week_no, "Week No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Transaction_no, "Transaction No#");
        excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.Band, "band");

        // Declare LINQ query
        IEnumerable<EDI> EDIs = from edi in excelFile.Worksheet<EDI>("EDI Data")
                   where DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(edi.EDI_date) , lastMonday) <= 7
                   select edi;

        // Loop through results
        foreach (EDI edi in EDIs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(edi.EDI_date);
        }

        return EDIs;
    }
```

Now, the error points to the foreach loop, believe it or not in the "foreach" statement... This is the particular line that causes the DataException:

```
>   foreach (EDI edi in EDIs)
```

Also, the Code for my class: EDI is as follows, there are 2 constructors

```
 class EDI
{
    public EDI(string edi_date, int week_no, int cust_no, int dist_no, int site_no, int card_no, int mileage, int quantity, int product_no, int month_no, int month_week_no, int transaction_no, int value, int band)
    {
        this.edi_date = edi_date;
        this.week_no = week_no;
        this.cust_no = cust_no;
        this.dist_no = dist_no;
        this.site_no = site_no;
        this.card_no = card_no;
        this.mileage = mileage;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.product_no = product_no;
        this.month_no = month_no;
        this.month_week_no = month_week_no;
        this.transaction_no = transaction_no;
        this.value = value;
        this.band = band;
    }

    public EDI()
    {
    }

    readonly string edi_date;
    public string EDI_date { get { return edi_date; } }

    readonly int week_no;
    public int Week_no { get { return week_no; } }

    readonly int dist_no;
    public int Dist_no { get { return dist_no; } }

    readonly int cust_no;
    public int Cust_no { get { return cust_no; } }

    readonly int site_no; 
    public int Site_no { get { return site_no; } }

    readonly int card_no;
    public int Card_no {get {return card_no;} }

    readonly int mileage;
    public int Mileage { get { return mileage; } }

    readonly int quantity;
    public int Quantity { get { return quantity; } }

    readonly int product_no;
    public int Product_no { get { return product_no; } }

    readonly int month_no;
    public int Month_no { get { return month_no; } }

    readonly int month_week_no;
    public int Month_week_no { get { return month_week_no; } }

    readonly int transaction_no;
    public int Transaction_no { get { return transaction_no; } }

    readonly int value;
    public int Value { get { return value; } }

    readonly int band;
    public int Band { get { return band; } }

}
```

Comment: Try to make your titles more specific to the actual problem, *Very Strange blah* isn't very descriptive. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has good advice on this

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'll keep that in mind. Cheers for the edit

Comment: What do you mean, you never refer to it? its on line 7-10: `excelFile.AddMapping<EDI>(x => x.EDI_date, "EDI Date");`?? maybe it automatically adds an `_`?

Comment: J. Chomel, I considered that and tried putting an @ symbol before "EDI Date" but it has the same result

Comment: The error message states that **Valid column names are: 'EDI Date'** and it appears exactly as it does in the spreadhseet

Comment: Yes but it says it's looking for EDI_Date, which seems to be different because of the `_`. Is there a possible parameter where you say the mapping feilds' spaces become ` `? Have you tried removing fields with no space? this could corner up the issue. Just saying.